# How to plot curve from polar coordinates data stored in a .txt file in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The program outputs polar coordinates to a text file the following way:

```
f = open(r'C:\Users\generic_user\Desktop\generic_txt_file.txt','w')

while n <= N-1:
    u_nn = u_n + k*v_n
    v_nn = v_n - k*u_n + k*mu*h**-2
    u_n = u_nn
    v_n = v_nn
    r_n = u_n**-1
    string_tita_n = str(n*k)
    string_r_n = str(r_n)
    f.write(string_tita_n + ' ' + string_r_n + '\n')
    n = n + 1

f.close()
```

The data looks like this:

```
0.0 59953022.59004443
0.06283185307179587 59989603.88149546
0.12566370614359174 60062900.551973954
0.1884955592153876 60173036.61693284
0.25132741228718347 60320124.93744161
0.3141592653589793 60504265.25498237
0.3769911184307752 60725541.31412035
```

I'm relatively new to programming in general and might be looking in the wrong places, but I'm struggling with matplotlib to make this work and would appreciate getting pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Alan! Are you struggling with reading the data from the file, or with the plotting? What have you tried so far? Could you update your question to provide such information?

Comment: @Michael Szczesny maybe I wasn't specific enough but that's because in reality I'm not someone used to coding and I'm doing this as part of assignment in a numerical methods class. The code so far works and I don't really intend on changing any of it. Back to the original point, I simply don't know where to start on how to make it so that the program can read the text file it wrote to and then plot it.

Comment: @natka_m thanks for the reply! Honestly, I'm struggling with both. I'm not sure what's the best way to go about either of the two. The only thing I'm certain about is that I can open the file for reading in a similar way to what I did before to write to it. Any sort of resources that might help me understand how to tackle these two tasks would be immensely helpful.

Comment: You don't need to read back the file, your program already knows the data… If you want to write a separate program that plots from saved data (not my reccomendation) you can slurp the vectors as `theta,rho=zip(*((float(x)for x in line.split())for line in open('YourFile.txt')))` RE plotting, please have a look at [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html).

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest way you can get it done:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = open(r'C:\Users\generic_user\Desktop\generic_txt_file.txt','r')
lines = file.readlines()

theta = []
rad = []

for line in lines:
    t, r = line.replace("\n","").split(" ")
    t = float(t)
    r = float(r)

    theta.append(t)
    rad.append(r)

plt.polar(theta, rad)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can have a look at the Pandas module and its method read_csv, which handles data reading.